# Just the FAQs, ma'am? (how to browse the FAQ)

Tags: support, search

At Stack Overflow, I put 'sofaq' into the search box. Most of what emerged was closed.

So I put `sofaq closed:0` into the search box.

Two things emerged.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you're missing is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag [sofaq] was deprecated and the tag [faq] is now favored. All FAQ questions are now located on meta, as well.

Comment: Just checked... There are 70+ open [sofaq] questions here on Meta, most of them migrated from SO proper (where the originals were then closed).

Comment: Hence the word deprecated and not eliminated. See also: HTML :P

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about searching on SO or here on meta? If it's the former I would expect a lot of the posts to be marked as closed as they would have been migrated here.

The policy is to keep SO focused on programming questions, so questions about how SO works - which includes questions about the FAQ will be closed and migrated.